# javassist:javassist vs org.javassist:javassist

Tags: java, maven, java-7

What is the difference between the Maven artifacts

`javassist:javassist` and `org.javassist:javassist`

In my project I've the first dependency with version `3.8` where as the second one I've introduced to resolve (StackMap verify)issues with *powermock*, as part of java 7 migration from 6 . The second dependency has latest of `3.18` version only. I still can't resolve my issues, but want to know the real difference between these two.

I've googled it but couldn't find any explanation. I hope it's not a duplicate question.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry My bad! I got confused with the version numbers, I thought the second one is '3.1.8'. Thanks for your time, I apologize for the confusion. TY!

Answer (score 7):

According [maven group id naming convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) group names should starts from domain name, so guys who develop javaassist changed group name in 3.13.0 release.

Versioning was naturaly continued after [3.12.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist) release from [3.13.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist).
Changes was done in r562 by *adinn* with comment:

> r562 | adinn | 2010-07-22 12:32:26 +0300 (Thu, 22 Jul 2010) | 1 line
>
> modified group id to org.javassist to keep the Sonatype repo people
>   happy -- fixes for JASSIST-96

[Link to JASSIST JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-96).

Comment: That's pretty useful info. Makes sense to me. TY!

Comment: good comprehensive answer, useful links to relevant JIRA etc.